# what are the uses of `const T&&`

Tags: c++, constants, move

> A move constructor of class T is a non-template constructor whose first parameter is T&&, const T&&, volatile T&&, or const volatile T&&, and either there are no other parameters, or the rest of the parameters all have default values.
>
> Source: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor

So `const T&&` is actually a thing. But doesn't the `const` defeat the purpose of `&&`? What are the practical uses for `const T&&`?

Comment: In addition to the linked answer you *can* actually define a meaningful move constructor for a class using a `const&&` parameter if the move operation is a no-op (as it is for e.g. `int`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph But in that case copying and moving is the same. If all class members are primitives like int there is no point in implementing move semantics at all.

Comment: @Eric That’s true. I was thinking that there might be a situation where the presence of a move constructor would change semantics based on testing via `std::is_move_constructible` but obviously this shouldn’t make a difference.